# WSO2 APIM Analytics Not Showing Any stats

Tags: wso2, analytics

We have setup WSO2 API manager and also APIM Analytics following the below link (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics)
but we are not able to see any analytical data in publisher or store.

We see the message **"Data Publishing Enabled. Generate some traffic to see statistics"**. However, even after generating the traffic, nothing appears. We also checked in the database and don't see any records added to the database tables.

Can anyone help in getting this issue resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled stat publishing correctly, you should see the following info log in wso2 API Manager side.

> INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} -  user admin
>   connected {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge}

You can also check if the data has published to the APIM Analytics node. Do the following.

1. Log into APIM Analytics management console - https://localhost:9444/carbon
2. Click on Data Explorer in Main menu.
3. Select table as 'ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_PERMINUTEREQUEST'.

You should see data in these tables, if the data has been published.

Basically, Analytics node will summarize the data and save the summarized data in the external database. When showing the data in the publisher and store, it will retrieve those data from the database.

If you are using mysql or any other database apart from h2, you need to point to the same stat database in APIM and Analytics nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply Pubci. I can see the records in the said table but on my publisher and store both analytics; I get the same message:
 "Data Publishing Enabled

Generate some traffic to see statistics"

Comment: Have you configured an external database such as mysql for WSO2 products or use the default h2 database?

Comment: I am using default h2 database.

Comment: If you are running on h2 database, you need to extract wso2am-2.0.0 and wso2am-analytics-2.0.0 packs to one location. At the startup if you have enabled stats, another folder called tmpStatDB will be created in that location which has the stat h2 database which shares among wso2am and wso2am-analytics.

Comment: Yes both are extracted to same location, tmpStatDB folder also getting created but on publisher and store, under analytics, have the same message and no stats.

Comment: How many APIs do you have? Make sure you have generated traffic for the APIs. There is known issue which the same response can be seen if the first API which is ordered by the alphabetical order does not have traffic.

Comment: @ajmalAbbasi any update on the issue? I'm facing the exact same problem, have generated traffic by populating the ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_PERMINUTEREQUEST table. Both the DAS and APIM are in one folder but still see the exact same message to generate traffic.